# My 2017 iMac has always been slow, why?

Tags: macos, imac, performance

**New iMac Specs:**

- Mid-2017 iMac
- Retina 4K 21.5 inch
- 3.0GHz quad-core Intel i5 CPU
- AMD Radeon Pro 555 with 2GB Memory
- 1TB Hard Drive
- 8GB RAM

macOS Catalina 10.15.2

It keeps hanging, lagging or freezing with the rainbow cursor for 1 or 2 seconds. Sometimes, even YouTube and Apple Music stops playing for the same time.

It's slow in everything, not just loading/writing on hard disk. I have tried a fresh installation of macOS with no results.

The memory is always empty and 70% of CPU stays in idle. I see no peak in usage on Activity Monitor. The hard disk is not full either. It's just strange. Has this been happening to anybody?

It has been like this forever. Having had a MacBook, I have never really used this machine except for now that I am home all the time.

Here is the report generated by EtreCheck: https://pastebin.com/4hbaLGte

Comment: Try opening Console.app and take a look at the logs to see if you can spot anything that might reveal a cause.

Comment: run etrecheck.  post results here;  https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-250000632

Comment: "Has always been slow" like since you got it?  Did you obtain new or from a 3rd party pre-owned?  Have you tried running [Apple Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731) (Hold `D` while booting).

Comment: @historystamp - why are you requesting the OP post the results of test outside of Ask Different and onto the Apple Discussion boards?

Comment: @Allan no that is a guide to use etre thing

Comment: @ankii - then why not put the link *here* as opposed to going offsite to get yet another link?  It *reads* "post results here <link>"

Comment: @Allan you missed the ";". The page is what google found. I can see how my short comment could be confusing.  I'm suggesting to run etrecheck. How would you suggest I write up a request to run etrecheck?  I've put other diagnostics in "your answer" and got dinged.

Comment: @historystamp - Here's a template you can use:  Download and run [Entrecheck](https://etrecheck.com/); it's free!  You can post the relevant section to the original question or if it's too big, use [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) and provide the link

Comment: @Allan regarding Apple diagnostics, it didn't output any error. I gave the reference code to Apple customer service and they said that my iMac didn't seem to have any hardware issue. I bought my iMac from Amazon.co.uk.

Comment: @historystamp here is the report link: https://pastebin.com/4hbaLGte

Comment: It seems to be reporting a failing hard drive issue.

Comment: I agree with @user168096.  The iMac you got from Amazon, was it their  “renewed” computer?  I’m getting lots of reports that the renewed isn’t as good as refurbished directly from Apple.  Now did you have this issue since you got it?  Also, did you upgrade to Catalina or did it come like that?  One last thing...why is SIP disabled?

Comment: Okie, that's a rather strange thing. I have actually never mingled with the security preferences. And yes, it was a refurbished one. I bought it back in 2018. The issue has always been there since day 1!

Comment: Did it come with any warranty or if so, is it still in effect?  The drive itself is fixable, but you’ll have to cut through the adhesive around the screen bezel.  If it’s not your cup of tea, you’ll have to take it in for service.  To find out which drive is failing issue the command `diskutil info disk0 | grep -i smart` do it again for `disk1`.  If it says “verified” it’s good, anything else and it’s failing.

Comment: It says verified. I have only one internal hard drive.

Comment: You don’t have a Fusion Drive?  What does `diskutil list` Come back with?

Comment: Those 'last of the old-style' iMacs with HDs are as slow as molasses. My folks have one. It was cheap & all they needed, but it takes an age to do anything, even boot. If you're used to an SSD Mac you will feel like it's stopped half the time. They're not just 'slow', they're.. 'is it broken?' slow.

Comment: enclosure : https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/owc-mercury-elite-pro  ssd drive: https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/SSD/OWC/Mercury_6G/  ( the price has gone up since I bought the pro version ) I got the separate drive since I was planning on swapping out my internal harddrive.

Comment: I have a 2014 mac mini with an internal harddrive.  The finder was slow, slow listing files. I bought an external drive enclosure and installed a ssd in the external.  Was like a bought a new machine. Used carbon copy cloner to copy over startup drive to external drive. hold to option key to pick what drive to boot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It was indeed a Hard Disk issue**. I have bought a Crucial SSD from Amazon and a USB 3.0 to SATA III connector. Since then, I have been using this configuration with the macOS being installed on the external SSD. I get r/w speeds of 480 MBps. The Mac runs magnificently. Nothing to complain.